# Передача значения переменной в классе

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть приложение Windows Form с несколькими формами. Есть код класса:

```
public void taker(int label_qnum)
    {
        if (label_qnum != 1)
            global_label_qnum = label_qnum - 1;
    }
public int giver_1()
    {
        glq = global_label_qnum;
        return glq;    
    }
```

`taker(int label_qnum)` берет значение `label_qnum` и сохраняет в `global_label_qnum`, чтобы перенести это значение на другую форму.
`giver_1()` должен отдать значение этой переменной, но возвращает всегда 0.

Как мне вернуть значение `label_qnum`? Возможно есть другой подход?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем классе, методы которого Вы показали в вопросе, `global_label_qnum` поле объявлено как поле экземпляра класса. Каждый раз, когда Вы создаете объект этого класса, оно инициализируется значением `0`. Объявите это поле как `static`, и оно станет принадлежать определению класса, а не объектам этого типа.

Comment: То есть нужно объявить класс как static или метод giver_1()?

Comment: @Irvin поле `global_label_qnum`